# Problema con servidor mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php7

Estoy teniendo un problema que nunca se me había presentado no se si es de **php** o **mysql**, cuando inserto un registro en la base de datos se devuelve el **id** del registro que se acaba de registrar en la bd, el problema que ahora estoy teniendo es que el id me lo esta devolviendo de la siguiente manera:

```
Ejemplo
 id: 96 -> id del ultimo registro en la bd

 id obtenido
 9
 6
```

Porque esta pasando esto??

Clase que utilizo para conectar **php** con **mysql**

```
<?php
class Database
{
    private static $db_host     = "localhost";
    private static $db_user     = "root";
    private static $db_password = "123";
    private static $db_database = "inventariobd";
        
    static function select($query)
    {
        $mysqli = new mysqli(self::$db_host, self::$db_user, self::$db_password, self::$db_database);
        $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
        $result = $mysqli->query($query);
        if(isset($result->num_rows))
        {
            if($result->num_rows > 0)
            {
                $rows = self::resultToArray($result);
                $result->free();
                $mysqli->close();
                return $rows;
            }
        }
        $mysqli->close();
        return FALSE;
    }

    static function insert($query)
    {
        $mysqli = new mysqli(self::$db_host, self::$db_user, self::$db_password, self::$db_database);
        $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
        $mysqli->multi_query($query);
        $insert_id = $mysqli->insert_id;
        $mysqli->close();
        return $insert_id;
    }

    static function update($query)
    {
        $mysqli = new mysqli(self::$db_host, self::$db_user, self::$db_password, self::$db_database);
        $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
        $success = $mysqli->query($query);
        $mysqli->close();
        return $success;
    }

    static function resultToArray($result)
    {
        $rows = array();
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        return $rows;
    }  
}
?>
```

insert.php

```
<?php
include_once("../../clases/class.Notificacion.php");
include_once("../../clases/class.Cancelacion.php");

extract($_POST);
# folio
# motivo

session_start();

$id_emisor = isset($_COOKIE["id_usuario"]) ? $_COOKIE["id_usuario"] : $_SESSION["id_usuario"];

date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');

$fecha = date("Y-m-d");
$hora = date("H:i:s");

$id_cancelacion = Cancelacion::insertCancelacion($folio, trim($motivo), $fecha);

if($id_cancelacion > 0)
{
    $insert = Notificacion::insert($id_emisor, 3, $id_cancelacion, $fecha, $hora);
    
    if($insert > 0)
        echo 1;
    else
        echo 0;
}
else
    echo 0;
?>
```

buscar.php

```
<?php
include_once("../../clases/class.Nota.php");

extract($_POST);
# folio

sleep(3);

$id_nota = Nota::getIDNota($folio);

echo $id_nota; 
?>
```

class.Cancelacion.php

```
<?php
  include_once("class.Database.php");

  class Cancelacion
  {
    ....
    public static function insertCancelacion($folio, $motivo, $fecha)
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO cancelacion(folio, motivo, status, fecha) VALUES('$folio', '$motivo', '0', '$fecha')";
        return Database::insert($query);
    }
    ....
  }
?>
```

class.Nota.php

```
<?php
   include_once("class.Database.php");

   class Nota
   {
      ....
      public static function getIDNota($folio)
      {
         $query = "SELECT id_nota FROM nota WHERE folio = $folio";
         $res = Database::select($query);
         return $res[0]["id_nota"];
      }
      ....
   }
?>
```

En esta parte de códgio hago registro en la base de datos y se supone que me devuelve el **id** del registro que acabo de hacer pero me lo esta devolviendo como o indico arriba

```
$id_cancelacion = Cancelacion::insertCancelacion($folio, trim($motivo), $fecha);
```

De igual forma me pasa en esta linea de código que extrae el id de un registro de la base de datos

```
$id_nota = Nota::getIDNota($folio);
```

Comment: ¿Hablas de la función `insert()`? ¿Puedes indicar el código donde invocas la función y manejas la respuesta? Parece que está creando un array por cada carácter de la cifra.

Comment: La función que muestra el resultado es la de resultToArray()?

Comment: El id obtenido te lo imprime 96 separado por un retorno de carro enter o son 2 consultas separadas una es id 9 y la otra id 6 ?

Comment: @A.Cedano hablo de las funciones select e insert